# how i can catch ctrl c without lose the console

Tags: visual-c++

On windows how I can catch CTRL+C without losing the use of the console in C++?

When I execute the `cin`, pressing either a number or pressing CTRL+C for `cin` it does the same thing - it changes the position of the input and re-accepts the input.
After that if I press CTRL+C and run `mysethandle` function then it goes into an infinite loop. However if I have pressed a number it works correctly.

How can I cancel the signal generated by `SetConsolCtrlHandler` and proceed with the `cin` without problems?

My code is:

```
// ctrlc.cpp : definisce il punto di ingresso dell'applicazione console.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int mysethandle(HANDLE stdd, bool x);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a,b,c,retu;
    DWORD mode;
    HANDLE stdd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    if (stdd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "handle non valido\n";
        return 0;
    }

    GetConsoleMode(stdd, &mode);
    mode &= ~ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT;

    primo:
    retu = 0;
    SetConsoleMode(stdd, mode);
    cout << "\ninserisci a: ";
    cin >> a;

    retu = mysethandle(stdd, true);
    if (retu==1) { goto primo; }

    SetConsoleMode(stdd, mode);

    secondo:
    retu = 0;
    cout << "inserisci b: ";
    cin >> b;

    retu = mysethandle(stdd, true);
    if (retu==1) { goto secondo; }

    c=a+b;
    cout << "\n " << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int mysethandle(HANDLE stdd, bool x)
{
    if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, x))
    {
        cout << "\n HAI PREMUTO CTRL C \n";
        SetConsoleMode(stdd,ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cpluspl

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cpluspl.

but honestly I not understend 3 things

1) how I do to turn off a signal ?

2) why the cin function does not work ?

3) when the cin function is deactivated ?